# psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known

Tags: django, postgresql, docker-compose

```
 docker-compose run web python3 manage.py migrate
WARNING: Found orphan containers (books_webapp_1) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
Starting books_db_1 ... 
Starting books_db_1 ... done
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
```

Comment: Will you please post your `docker-compose.yml` file content and maybe the output of `docker ps` command?

Comment: Dockerfile
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.7
# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code
# Install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system
# Copy project
COPY . /code/

Comment: docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'
services:
web:
build: .
command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
volumes:
- .:/code
ports:
- 8000:8000

Comment: docker-compose up -d

Comment: Please edit your question and add these details to the question itself. it is not readable in the comments.